# Как правильно заменить через javascript фоновые изображения заданные из css, чтобы повысить производительность

Tags: javascript, производительность

Стоит вот такая задача. Клиенты задают фоновые изображения для блоков через админку ворпресс. Они автоматически прописываются в css. Я хочу, чтобы, если пользователь заходит на сайт с мобильного, в качестве фонового изображения грузились версии "thumbnail" заданного клиентом фона ("thumbnail" сгенерированы ворпрессом автоматически при загрузке изображения).

Для этого я прописал скрипт, который на мобильном экране (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 420) добавляет элементу встроенный стиль background-image с маленьким изображением и перебивает стиль background-image из css.

То есть все хорошо, изображения меняются в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Однако у меня возник такой вопрос, так как не ориентируюсь в теме. Имеет ли вообще смысл это для повышения производительности? То есть в каком порядке обрабатываются различные вещи? Возможно, скрипт заменил изображение, но к тому времени изображение, заданное через css, уже было загружено браузером? То есть весь смыл в том, чтобы на маленьком экране большое изображение не грузилось, а грузилось маленькое. Где правильно разместить скрипт (он у меня стоит внизу страницы и определяет изображение, которое нужно заменить через getComputedStyle)? Возможно есть лучшие решения?

Сразу оговорюсь, очевидные решения типа прописать меньшее изображение в css через медиа-запрос не подходят, так как клиент в любой момент может задать любое изображение. Нужно, чтобы маленькая версия подхваывалась автоматически. Аналогично изображение на полный размер контейнера с абсолютным позиционированием тоже нет. Это должно загружаться только стандартно через админку и прописываться в css, как background-image.

Вот как-то так. Большое спасибо, если кто-то подскажет что-то дельное.

Comment: В браузере в консоли на вкладке "сеть" можно посмотреть, какие изображения загружаются первыми. Если первыми будут мелкие, а крупных не будет, то ничего больше делать не нужно. Иначе в элемент можно писать `data-background` и скриптом такие фоны превращать в реальные, тогда браузер не будет изначально их понимать и отображать.

Comment: Если фоны идут изначально из таблицы CSS, а не в элементах, то в эту таблицу можно просто на php вставить кусок стилей с медиа-запросом, тогда скрипт писать не нужно будет.

Comment: Так же можно перед выводом таких элементов из php добавлять просто тег style, в котором будет медиазапрос для мобильника, перебивающий дефолтный стиль элемента.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Спасибо большое дружище. Посмотрел на вкладке "сеть". Все работает. Грузятся только маленькие картинки. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто сделать медиа-запросами:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../../bg-big.jpg');
}

@media all and (max-width: 420px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('../../bg-small.jpg');
  }
}
```